# How to manipulate CSV. file on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a CSV.file which looks just fine. Please see the picture below:

[image: MSCI World Return in CSV.file]

However, when I open the file in Jupyter Notebook, the columns are concanated. Please see below:

[image: MSCI World Return in Jupyter Notebook]

I used the following code to open the file:

```
import pandas as pd
MSCI = pd.read_csv("/Users/user/data/MSCI Wolrd returns.csv", header=0, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

    MSCI.head()
```

How could I go about fixing this problem? 
How can I open the file so that the dates will be in one column and the values in the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SOlution

Its because, in your data `seperator` is `;` and pandas use `default` comma `,` as seperator.

Try this

```py
import pandas as pd
MSCI = pd.read_csv("/Users/user/data/MSCI Wolrd returns.csv", header=0, index_col=0, parse_dates=True,sep=";")

MSCI.head()
```

If this solution is answer to your question then accept it else comment whats the problem.